# Spark job keeps having output folder already exists exception

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a spark job, and it kept failing with output folder already exists exceptions. I indeed removed the output folder before the job. Looks like the folder is created during the job and it confused other nodes/threads. It happens randomly but not always.

Comment: can you show us the code which creates and writes the files? is it HDFS or some other FS?

Answer (score 2):

```
rdd.write().format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("location");
```

This should solve the issue of file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a local filesystem path, then be aware that the folder gets created on all workers. So you probably have to delete it from all of them.